# MS Graph API - Booking Business - Adding Staff Members with "administrator" role creates "externalGuest"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I try to add staff members with an `administrator` role to an existing Booking using MS Graph APIs following MS Doc in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-post-staffmembers?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

**The user I acquire token for**

The user that I am sending to MS Graph API to get a token for, is a Global Admin in my Azure AD tenant and also has full Office 365 licenses including the `booking` application.

**The App registered in the Azure AD**

The App I've registered there has granted access to MS Graph APIs for all the Bookings and Users permissions plus `Directory.ReadWrite.All`. Here's a screenshot for that:

[image]

**The Problem**

Regardless of the value for the `role` property in the request payload, the staff member always gets created with an `externalGuest` role. Here's a screenshot from the postman:

[image]

And here is a list of possible role values from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/bookingstaffmember?view=graph-rest-beta):

[image]

I've also tried to update that staff member to change the role to `administrator` to see if that would help, but even in the update, it does not change the role value.

I've Googled this around and went to a few threads I could find, but yet nothing helpful found. Is this a known issue? Or is there a fix for that? Anything like a particular license I'm missing?

Appreciate your opinions.

Comment: Its happening because the email address which you are giving is not present in your tenant. Please try giving a user email address in your tenant and try to add a role like 'viewer' or 'guest'. It worked for me.

Comment: thanks, Shiva - it worked just fine!

Comment: Glad to here that it worked. Moving this to Answer.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening because the email address which you are giving is not present in your tenant. Please try giving a user email address in your tenant and try to add a role like 'viewer' or 'guest'. It worked for me.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/bookingBusinesses/TestBookingCalendar@xyz.live/staffmembers

{
    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingStaffMember",
    "colorIndex":1,
    "displayName":"ABC",
    "emailAddress":"NKS@xyz.live",
    "role@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingStaffRole",
    "role":"guest",
    "useBusinessHours":true,
    "workingHours@odata.type":"#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingWorkHours)",
    "workingHours":[
        {
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkHours",
            "day@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.dayOfWeek",
            "day":"monday",
            "timeSlots@odata.type":"#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot)",
            "timeSlots":[
                {
                    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot",
                    "end":"17:00:00.0000000",
                    "start":"08:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkHours",
            "day@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.dayOfWeek",
            "day":"tuesday",
            "timeSlots@odata.type":"#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot)",
            "timeSlots":[
                {
                    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot",
                    "end":"17:00:00.0000000",
                    "start":"08:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkHours",
            "day@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.dayOfWeek",
            "day":"wednesday",
            "timeSlots@odata.type":"#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot)",
            "timeSlots":[
                {
                    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot",
                    "end":"17:00:00.0000000",
                    "start":"08:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkHours",
            "day@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.dayOfWeek",
            "day":"thursday",
            "timeSlots@odata.type":"#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot)",
            "timeSlots":[
                {
                    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot",
                    "end":"17:00:00.0000000",
                    "start":"08:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkHours",
            "day@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.dayOfWeek",
            "day":"friday",
            "timeSlots@odata.type":"#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot)",
            "timeSlots":[
                {
                    "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.bookingWorkTimeSlot",
                    "end":"17:00:00.0000000",
                    "start":"08:00:00.0000000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```